# Python sqlalchemy query label or alias result of two columns as new column name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables and one of the table has two columns and a row will only contain data in one of the columns:

Table 2:

```
|  column1  |  column2  |
-------------------------
| something |   Null    |
-------------------------
| Null      | something |
-------------------------
```

I am trying to do something like:

```
q = session.query(Table1.column1, (Table2.column1, Table2.column2).label('content')) \
.outerjoin(Table2) \
.all()

for v in q:
    x = v.column1
    content = v.content
    print(x, content)
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sql coalesce should help. It will return the first non-null value among the list of values.

```
from sqlalchemy import func     
q = session.query(Table1.column1, func.coalesce(Table2.column1, Table2.column2).label('content')) \
    .outerjoin(Table2) \
    .all()
```